# Extract data into datatable to draw multiple graphs on one chart

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq, statistics

I am working on a project that aims to extract and treat data for statitics purpose.
Let's say I have many elements "E" and each element has a list of fields {F1, F2, F3, ...}.
My main table looks like the  following:

[image]

I need to extract data by elementID into a data table with "Date" as Key.

```
[{"key": "date1",
 "F1": "value",
 "F2": "value"}
,{"key": "date2",
 "F1": "value",
 "F2": "value"}
,{"key": "date3",
 "F1": "value",
 "F2": "value"}
,{....}]
```

My current implementation is the following does the next:

1) Query from database by field and order by date in a `Dictionary<DateTime, double>`

2) Check and fill missing values in each `Dictionary`.

3) Loop through the list or `Dictionary` by key and fill a `DataRow` a row by row.

I don't think that this is the ultimate solution, I have been trying to optimize code. But I am not really sure in wich layer I should focus. Is there any possible way to get the required structure using a select from database ( no need to further loops ) ?

Comment: _data table_ means `DataTable` and _main table_ is the table in the database or also an in-memory `DataTable`?

Comment: Yes, by main table I meant what exists in my database. For the DataTable, I need its structure to pas it to a Javasript api for charts.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that clear, however, i assume that you want to group by the date-part of the `DateTime` and select a dictionary where this date is the key and the value is a `List<double>`.

Then you don't need a `DataTable` at all. Instead of a `double` i would use custom classes with all properties. Assuming that `mainTable` is already a `DataTable` with the raw data:

```
public class ElementMeasurement
{
    public Element Element { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public class Element
{
    public int ElementID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use `Enumerable.GroupBy` which is part of `System.Linq`:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, List<ElementMeasurement>> dateMeasurements = mainTable.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<DateTime>("Date").Date)
    .ToDictionary(g => 
        g.Key,
        g => g.Select(row => new ElementMeasurement
            {
                Element = new Element { ElementId = row.Field<int>("ElementId") },
                Field = row.Field<string>("Field"),
                Value = row.Field<double>("Value"),
                TimeOfMeasurement = row.Field<DateTime>("Date")
            }).ToList()
);
```

**Edit**: "Well I should let you know that it is a huge table with thousands of miles of rows!"

I didnt know that the table was not already in memory. Then this might be too memory expensive. So maybe a loop on the DataReader which yields rows ordered by Date is more efficient. Then you could still use my classes above to keep it readable and maintainable but fill the Dictionary step-by-step.

For example (assuming SQL-Server):

```
var dateMeasurements = new Dictionary<DateTime, List<ElementMeasurement>>();
using(var con = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT e.* FROM Elements e ORDER BY Date,ElementId,Field,Value", con))
{
    con.Open();
    using (var rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    while(rd.Read())
    {
        DateTime timeOfMeasurement = rd.GetDateTime(rd.GetOrdinal("Date"));
        DateTime dateOfMeasurement = timeOfMeasurement.Date;
        List<ElementMeasurement> measurements = null;
        if (!dateMeasurements.TryGetValue(dateOfMeasurement, out measurements))
        {
            measurements = new List<ElementMeasurement>();
            dateMeasurements.Add(dateOfMeasurement, measurements);
        }
        var measurement = new ElementMeasurement
        {
            Element = new Element { ElementId = rd.GetInt32(rd.GetOrdinal("ElementId")) },
            Field = rd.GetString(rd.GetOrdinal("Field")),
            Value = rd.GetDouble(rd.GetOrdinal("Value")),
            TimeOfMeasurement = timeOfMeasurement
        };
        measurements.Add(measurement);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I did understand your code, you are loading mainTable.AsEnumerable() in-memory? Well I should let you know that it is a huge table with thousands of miles of rows!

Comment: @mahoosh: I didnt know that the table was not already in memory. Then this might be too memory expensive. So maybe a loop on the `DataReader` which yields rows ordered by `Date` is more efficient. Then you could still use my classes above to keep it readable and maintainable but fill the `Dictionary`  step-by-step.

Comment: @mahoosh: Edited my answer to provide a sample.